# Image doesn't scale inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When an image is inside a flexbox it doesn't scale properly (height doesn't auto adjust).

Here is example of it working outside flex and not working inside;

```css
.image-size{
  height:auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<img class="image-size" src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/233274/arrow-circle.png" alt="circle" />
<div class="container">
  <img class="image-size" src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/233274/arrow-circle.png" alt="circle" />
</div>
```

What is happening here?

Comment: What's wrong? The both of them have their width set not height.Nor does the flex parent have a width or height

Comment: The first image scales, the second image doesn't, did you click run?

Comment: Where is the scaling? With applied width of 300px, they are both the same size

Comment: how can you not see?  The first image has height of 300px automatically set, second image has height of 2400px.

Comment: Giving negative scores for free help-trials is never a good idea. Your aim is not described, but judging by the random usage of the flexbox model, I think the problem here is fundamental.

Comment: giving negative scores to solutions that dont work is the purpose of the rating system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a common problem with Flexbox. You must put your image into a `display:block` item. `figure` is by default a block container. Here is a work around :

```css
    .image-size{
      height:auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
    figure{
      width : 300px;
    }
    .container{
      display: flex;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <figure>
        <img class="image-size" src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/233274/arrow-circle.png" alt="circle" />
      </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like wrapping an `img` in `div` will also work.

Comment: `div` and `figure` have `display block` property by default so their behavior is the same.